# Changed URL of Wordpress Blog and now site doesn't display pages

Tags: wordpress

All,
I had a wordpress site at the following URL:

http://website.com/new_site/

I just uploaded all of my files to the root folder so now it looks like:

http://website.com/

I read the Wordpress Codex and already updated my Wordpress URI and Site Address URL to the new site.

I also tried to update my database tables using the following script that Wordpress recommends:
http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

I did a find and replace for search string "/new_site/" to be "/" but none of my pages are stil being displayed. Does anyone have any other recommendations on how to do this? What should I check?

FYI, my homepage works fine it just won't display any of the other pages that I've created.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple fix. I just had to update my permalink settings. Once I did that, my site works great!